# Kotlin and Android Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

**Updated 21.06.2015**

I wanna try kotlin and android databinding in a same project. But when I add to kotlin-gradle-plugin dependency I cannot build even an empty project anymore with error:

[cannot generate view binders java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/ExtensionFunctionImpl](https://gist.github.com/stepango/dca7e616ee595e7e29d6)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta3'
      classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.12.613"
  }
}
```

Any workaroud to make it work together?

Comment: Please check with Kotlin 0.12.613, it must be fixed

Comment: @AndreyBreslav thanks, new kotlin version solves the problem i described, but still i cannot compile even an empty project vith error: "[ERROR]: cannot generate view binders java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/ExtensionFunctionImpl"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately,this is caused by a kotlin version inconsistency between databinding and kotlin plugin.
We'll remove kotlin dependency from the plugin on rc1 but until then you would need to use kotlin 0.11.91.
Also, since kotlin's annotation processor support is limited at this moment and data binding is using annotation processor; they probably won't work well (though I have not tried).

Comment: Since M12, the annotation processing should work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunatelly using 0.11.91 fails with other error if i try to sync project with gradle, looks like 0.11.91 - just not support latest Android Studio build

Comment: @yigit do you still have kotlin code in DataBinding?

Comment: Yes but next version will be released with kotlin 1.0 so this won't be a problem anymore